# Display integer in printf function

Tags: c

I have one piece like this program:

```
printf("%.2d", 5);
```

I think it should only display: `5` But it displayed: `05`. Can you explain to me how it works?

Comment: Check this [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is known as precision modifier which is written as `.number`, and has slightly different meanings for the different conversion specifiers

For floating point numbers (e.g. %f), it controls the number of digits printed after the decimal point:

```
printf( "%.3f", 1.2 );
```

will print:

```
1.200
```

If the number provided has more precision than is given, it will round. For example:

```
printf( "%.3f", 1.2348 );
```

will print:

```
1.235
```

For g and G, it will control the number of significant figures displayed. This will impact not just the value after the decimal place but the whole number.

```
printf( "%.3f\n%.3g\n%.3f\n%.3g\n", 100.2, 100.2, 3.1415926, 3.1415926 );
```

will print:

```
100.200 // %.3f, putting 3 decimal places always
100     // %.3g, putting 3 significant figures
3.142   // %.3f, putting 3 decimal places again
3.14    // %.3g, putting 3 significant figures
```

For integers, on the other hand, the precision it controls the minimum number of digits printed:

```
printf( "%.3d", 10 );
```

will print:

```
010
```

Finally, for strings, the precision controls the maximum length of the string displayed:

```
printf( "%.5s\n", "abcdefg" );
```

will print:

```
abcde
```

Source: [Printf Format Strings](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `2` in `"%.2d"` means you want to print at least 2 digits. Similarly, if you wanted to print at least 3 digits, you could use `"%.3d"`. If you wanted no additional digits (ie. no padding with 0's), you could use `"%d"` on its own.

[Man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) are your best friend